# Stroke amelioration

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, psychopharmacology, brain, pathology

Excessive sugar, like Pepsi, is considered harmful. However, I am wondering if it could be helpful if taken by a victim of stroke during or immediately after a stroke, or somewhat after a stroke? My heuristic reasoning is partly that the brain likes energy in the form of sugar, and so if animals have evolved a method to ameliorate a loss of blood supply to a part of the brain, then that method probably needs energy, and needs to be provided quickly.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an ischemic stroke, the oxygen-rich blood supply to part of your brain is reduced. With a hemorrhagic stroke, there is bleeding in the brain.

During an ischemic stroke, brain cells die of a lack of oxygen. Nutrient supply is indeed cut off as well, but the most acute threat to neurons is lack of oxygen. Because if their high activity, they need a continuous supply of oxygen. Bathing them in Pepsi cola won't stop them from suffocating. Note that they can switch to other fuel sources than glucose and hence nutrient supply isn't the critical factor.

During a hemorrhagic stroke there is pressure buildup in the brain and subsequent mechanical damage. Also here, pepsi coke won't relieve the damage done.

Last but not least, digesting food takes a lot of time. Oxygen deprivation kills neurons in minutes.

<sub>**Source**

[WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/stroke/tc/stroke-what-happens)</sub>